# shared preference in android

Tags: android

I am new in android development.

I've an activity in which I'm taking user name and password.and I'm passing those values to a web service which returns a key as a response.i have one toggle button in my activity. now if the user checks the toggle button that means he want to keep logged in  and the user should be redirected to next activity when he next time log-in.

If toggle button is checked I'm storing user name, password and key in shared preference.
 but I'm not getting how to retrieve those details next time(i.e when user next time log-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Checkbox add a sharedPreferences Boolean value when the user checks/unchecks on keep logged in. Then as you call onCreate of Login activity you need to check this and call the next activity if the boolean value is true.

Answer (score 6):

```
userDetails = this.getSharedPreferences("userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor edit = userDetails.edit();
edit.clear();
edit.putString("username", txtUname.getText().toString().trim());
edit.putString("password", txtPass.getText().toString().trim());
edit.commit();
Toast.makeText(this, "Login details are saved..", 3000).show();
```

this way you can fetch preference

```
String Uname = userDetails.getString("username", "");
String pass = userDetails.getString("password", "");
```

and check for login this way

```
if(Uname=="" && pass =="")
//Go to login
else
//Go to Next Activity
```

try like this

best of luck

Comment: It's not really wise to store password in shared preferences - otherwise it's ok

Comment: @Dr.Jackal..Thanks for Ur quick reply sir...but I'm through up to this...now I'm not able to understand that when user next time log-in ,how to redirect to the next activity...

Comment: @android you can check username and password from your preference if its already contains username and password then you can redirect to your activity else you can redirect to log in page

Answer (score 2):

try this for store value in sharePreferences..

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Share", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("Value", 1 );
editor.commit();
```

for get value

```
prefs.getInt("Value",0);
```

/////////////////////////////////////////

```
String Uname = userDetails.getString("username", "");
String pass = userDetails.getString("password", "");

if(Uname=="" && pass =="")
//Go to login
else
//Go to Next Activity
```

Answer (score 0):

Then he can encrypt the password  and store it in sharedpreferences whenever he needs the password he can get that encrypted password from the sharedpreferences and decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid storing the user password.
For each user, consider storing:

```
the user id
a random seed unique to this user 
a hash of the seeded password.
```

The user will need to reenter his password, then you can add the stored seed to the entered password and apply the hash algorithm X times to the seeded password. Then compare the hash to the stored hash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://prashantsolanki3.github.io/Secure-Pref-Manager/ for saving and retrieving shared preferences securely and with ease.

The keys and values are automatically encrypted.

Save:

```
SecurePrefManager.with(this)
            .set("user_name")
            .value("LoremIpsum")
            .go();
```

Retrieve:

```
String userName = SecurePrefManager.with(this)
            .get("user_name")
            .defaultValue("unknown")
            .go();
```

Hope this helps!