# How to send variables from Main activity to multiple activities in android?

Tags: android, bundle, global-state

Iam trying to create an application that have

1. MainActivity
   it is a login page , it contain 4 variable, when i click the login button,
        it goes to another activity HomeTab using an intent 
         `Intent i = new Intent(FirstMain.this,Home_tab.class);`
         `startActivity(i);`
2. HomeTab - it has three Tab views.
                a. Profile
                b. Account
                c. Settings

My problem is how to pass that 4 variables from the MainActivity to the 3 activities in the Tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two options.

1. you can use intent.
2. you can use sharedpreferences.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a Bundle as extra parameter in an intent

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "peanuts");
bundle.putInteger("key2", 100);
i.putExtras(bundle);
```

Then to retrieve it

```
final Bundle parameters = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String food = parameters.getString("key");
```

Comment: This is just for one activity which is triggered one not for multiple activities which aren't triggered yet.

Answer (score 3):

In Class 1:

```
i.putExtras("Variable1", "Value1");
i.putExtras("Variable2", 2);
i.putExtras("Variable3", true);
startActivity(i);
```

In Class 2:

```
String Var1 = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("Variable1");
int Var2 = this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Variable2");
boolean Var3 = this.getIntent().getExtras().getBool("Variable3");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass them in the Intent you use to launch the HomeTab activity (see [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)).

Answer (score 1):

In Login Activity send the variable via Intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstMain.this,Home_tab.class);
i.putExtra("var1", "username");
i.putExtra("var2", "activity";
startActivity(i);
```

In the Home_Tab get the Intent

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String id = intent.getStringExtra("var1");
String name = intent.getStringExtra("var2");
```

For info on shared preferences [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013341/shared-preference-in-android)

Comment: i don't want to pass data to Home_Tab Activity,  it take two times to pass data. ie; first pass data from MainActivity to Home_tab Activity, then from Home_tab to three tabActivity ,I want to pass the data to 3 tabActivity directly. is there any way.... i think shared preference is the better way ..is there anyone can give an example ...

Comment: i don't want to pass data to Home_Tab Activity,  it take two times to pass data. ie; first pass data from MainActivity to Home_tab Activity, then from Home_tab to three tabActivity ,I want to pass the data to 3 tabActivity directly.when i use two intent in the MainActivity, ie; one for redirecting to Home_tab Activity and another for passing values to one of the tabActivity then it shows error.. is there any way.... i think shared preference is the better way ..is there anyone can give an example ...

Answer (score 1):

use intent.putExtra to pass values you want

```
Intent i=new Intent(FirstMain.this,Home_tab.class);
i.putExtra("Profile", "profiledata");
i.putExtra("Account", "Account data");
startActivity(i)
```

and get those passing values in next activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String id = intent.getStringExtra("Profile");
String name = intent.getStringExtra("Account");
```

Check 
[How do I get extra data from intent on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233873/how-to-get-extra-data-from-intent-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number of "global" variables, you can setup a "BaseActivity" that inherits from Activity does not have a cooresponding view, and then have all your other Activities inherit from BaseActivity rather than directly from Activity.

That allows you to have public shared variables on BaseActivity that all your other activities that inherit from that can access.

Obviously be careful with this technique, it could easily be really messy and lead to globals that shouldn't be global, etc.  But it is handy for cleaning up code that is duplicated across views (shared methods on BaseActivity) or passing information between views, like a loggedIn state.