# what is best idea for login and register in android + phpmysql(bigginer)

Tags: php, android, session, authentication

i'm expert in php , mysql programming...
i write a php,mysql script that users can login, register, have profiles and so much more...
i'm just a beginner in android programming...
i write a android app that have a webview for show mobile version of my site..

**i want know:**
 how can i check the user logged / or not (sessions created with php when user login is success)? (really i want check for example $_SESSION['logged'] in my android app for show a specific  activity (if session exsits, show activity1 , and if not exit show activity2)

important note : i'm a bigginer in android!

sorry for my English (English, is not my native language!)

**my problem solved!**
You can use this tutorial ...... that is very very easy and understandable ...
[Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

Comment: Are you creating android app or mobile webview ?

Comment: i create mobile app in webview... but i want do register and login in android instead of webview

Comment: then use json handlers for passing user details and based on the json response login to the app, then save user details in shared preference   for future use

Comment: i don't know what shared preference is!! any reference?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013341/shared-preference-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a professional. Hope I can solve your problem.
I have two method to do the member system.

First, I will create a Data model like User.java

-> User.java

```
class User{
 private String username = "";
 private String password = "";

// Getter and Setter..
}
```

while a user is login, create a new user object.

```
User user = new User();
user.setPassword(...);
user.setUsername(...);
```

When you need to get information from server by httprequest. What you need to do is get the information from User object

```
 Url url = new Url("http://your.server/index.php?username=" + user.getUsername() + "&password=" + user.getPassword());
 HttpURLRequest conn = url.openConnection();
 .......
```

Further information.
I usually save the cookie from the login process.

```
ArrayList<String> cookiesList = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String, List<String>> mHeaderMap = mConnection.getHeaderFields();
String headername = "";
for(int i = 0; (headername = mConnection.getHeaderFieldKey(i)) != null; i++){
    if(headername.equals("Set-Cookie")){
        cookiesList.add(mConnection.getHeaderField(i));
    }
}
```

Then if you send another login request. you use the cookie again and send to the server.

```
mConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
```

> More Information here.

On server side.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_GET.count() > 0)
$username = $_GET['username'];
if($_GET.count() > 0)
$password = $_GET['password'];
$arr = array();

if($_SESSION['username'] == $username && $_SESSION['password'] == password){
 $arr = array("isValid" => true, "message" => "");
}else{
 $arr = array("isValid" => false, "message" => "");
}
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

On android

```
if(isValid){
  startActicity(....)
}
```

Comment: your answer help me but not completely... tnx alot but i want read seassion ...

Comment: You should do it in server side I think.

Actually the cookie you catch on client side is referring to the session on server side.

Comment: [More information about Cookie and Session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie)

Hope I can help you. :D

Comment: For android, it would be suitable to use Shared Preferences for User Settings instead of putting it on a Map because Map uses Heap memory and after closing the app, values saved into it will also be gone.